# Galaxy A3 samsung can;t be read in my laptop

Tags: samsung-galaxy-a3

I was always being able to transfer my photos from my Samsung A3 Galaxy to my laptop. But recently i am unable to do it. Please advise how do i fix this problem.
Thank you
Faribel

Comment: When did you lost the connectivity? was it after doing any resets in your phone or laptop? (If so this could be a driver issue) Please elaborate the question.

Answer (score 0):

Connect device through usb:

Then permission to allow from mobile
If not popup visible then you can try from slide down to choose USB options. You can try all those options to visible mobile on your filemanager.

If still not availble then you can try through developer option then on option.

Which operating system you have used in your laptop.

You can also connect using `xander` or such app to laptop through brower you can access then mobile.